# Angular Material datepicker -selected date and radio buttons value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a matdatepicker inside mat-radio-group as one of the options. When the user selects the date, that value should be passed as the value of the radio button, how do i do that. Right now I have the datechange & dateinput events that passes the value and formats it on the typescript side. Is there any easy method to do this. I just the date to be displayed in date/month/year format, dont need any other data.
Here is the code:

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="installType">
            <mat-radio-button value="8555">8555 - Delay Crew</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value="9000">9000 - Self Install</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button [value] = "dp" (click)="datePicker.open()">
                <mat-input-container>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" placeholder="Post Date">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker">
                        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon></mat-icon>
                    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #datePicker (dateInput)="addEvent($event)" 
                    (dateChange)="addEvent($event)" ></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-input-container>
            </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
```

Here is the typescript part:

```
 export class AddsaleComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  dp: any;

  formatDate(date: Date) {
    const day = date.getDate();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
  }

  constructor(private wos: WorkorderService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({  
      installType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),  
    })
  }

  onSale(form) {
    this.wos.postWorkOrder(this.form.value);
  }

  addEvent(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
   this.dp = this.formatDate(event.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `ts` file as well?

Comment: @bugs, I edited the original post with typescript. Thanks.

Comment: Could someone here have an answer for this post? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for this after a lot of digging. Posting it here if someone here comes across the same issue. All I needed to add was the [(ngModel)] to the mat-radio-group and do some validation in the backend if the chosen radio button is the dataapicker. The ngModel passes the value to the component ts code and the datechange events on the datepicker passes the date as well to the component ts
Here is the code.

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="installStatus" [(ngModel)]="installStatus">
            <mat-radio-button value="8555">8555 - Delay Crew</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value="9000">9000 - Self Install</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value="FFM" (click)="datePicker.open()">
                <mat-input-container>
                    <input #date matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" placeholder="FFM"
                    (dateInput)="addEvent(date)" (dateChange)="addEvent(date)">
                    <mat-datepicker #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-input-container>
            </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
```

Typescript Part

```
ngOnInit() {
this.form = new FormGroup({
  accountNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, 
    Validators.pattern('[0-9-]*'), 
    Validators.minLength(13), 
    Validators.maxLength(13)]),
  customerName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z. ]+')]),
  packageName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  campaignName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),  
  notes: new FormControl(''),
  entryDate: new FormControl(moment().format('ll')),
  installStatus: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
})


 }

  onSale(form) {
    if (this.form.value.installStatus !== "FFM") { this.datePickerInput = this.form.value.installStatus; }
    else { 
      var ffmDate = moment(this.datePickerInput);
      this.datePickerInput = moment(ffmDate).format('ll');
    }
    this.form.setValue({
      accountNumber: this.form.value.accountNumber, 
      customerName: this.form.value.customerName,
      packageName:this.form.value.packageName, 
      campaignName:this.form.value.campaignName, 
      notes:this.form.value.notes,
      entryDate:this.form.value.entryDate, 
      installStatus:this.datePickerInput
    });
    this.wos.postWorkOrder(this.form.value);
  }

  addEvent(date: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    this.datePickerInput = date.value;
  }
```